# update of preview images for embedded files in Open XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I have an excel table embedded in a Powerpoint slide which I want to edit. openxml sdk reads the slide and results in one ImagePart and one EmbeddePackage part, which represents the worksheet I'm editing. the only problem is the user has to double click on the table for it to update. to my understanding ppt produces an xrf image and references it to the ImagePart, and only does so every-time the user interacts with the table. Is there a workaround to update the view before the file is opened?

```
        public static void EditEmbeddedTable(ref SlidePart slidePart, int workSheetIndex, int skip, string data, CellValues dtype, string columnName, int rowIndex, int dependantSheetIndex)
        {
            EmbeddedPackagePart? epp = slidePart.EmbeddedPackageParts.Skip(skip).FirstOrDefault();
            if (epp == null)
                return;
            using (Stream str = epp.GetStream())
            {
                using (MemoryStream mr = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    str.CopyTo(mr);
                    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(mr, true))
                    {
                        WorksheetPart? worksheetPart = ExcelHelper.GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadsheet, "Data");
                        if (worksheetPart == null) return;
                        var worksheet = worksheetPart.Worksheet;
                        ExcelHelper.setCell(ref worksheet, columnName, (uint)rowIndex, data, dtype);
                        WorksheetPart dependantWorkSheet = ExcelHelper.GetWorksheetPartByName(spreadsheet, "Portfolio");
                        if (dependantWorkSheet == null) return;
                        ExcelHelper.UpdateAllCellForumlas(spreadsheet, dependantWorkSheet.Worksheet);
                        spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
                        spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;
                    }
                    str.Position = 0;
                    str.SetLength(0);
                    mr.WriteTo(str);

                }
            }

        }
```

The following updates the table as needed, how do I get this back as an ImagePart in ppt?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you can try this:

1. Get the `ImagePart` from them `MainDocumentPart`
2. Read the current object (image or what ever), convert: `image/object` to `Stream` and feed the `ImagePart` with that, like: `imagePart.FeedData(stream)`